# Android intent filter - check if another app started activity

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, android-activity

I'm catching an intent filter from another app, which sends no data. In my manifest, I start my login screen.
Is there a way to check if my app was started by a user or from the other app?

I have no control over the other app, therefor I can't make it send some data.

Comment: Is the other app from you also?

Comment: If you're already catching the intent succesfully, isn't it possible to check the intent that started your app by using `Intent intent = getIntent();` in your oncreate to see if you can identify that it came from the other app you mention?

Comment: It works!
Thanks!

Btw, is there a timeframe that has to pass before I can accept your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: No, you can't accept a comment as an answer, but I'll add my comment as an actual answer so you'll be able to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already catching the intent succesfully, it's possible to check the intent that started your app by using `Intent intent = getIntent();` in your oncreate to see if you can identify that it came from the other app you mention.